# Soundproofing casement windows

Tags: windows, sound-proofing

I have three casement windows facing a busy street in an urban area and noise does get into the room. I noticed that the window panels (moving parts) meet the frame directly, meaning there is no gasket of any type.

Do you think applying 1/8" foam weatherstripping tape along the perimeter of the frame where the window forms a seal will reduce the noise coming in?

Answer (score 1):

It might *help*, if that is where most of the sound is coming through. Newer windows have varying sound-transmission ratings (the more you spend, the better they are at blocking noise, generally). If you have old single-pane windows... it might not help much because the sound is coming through the whole thing.

I had a room where I needed to sleep in the day but the windows were old single-pane units. I had to place thick foam panels against them, tightly, when I was sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

Sound insulation comprises three major elements…

Mass
Damping/absorption
Air-gapping

These three interplay in a highly complex way.

[This is hugely over-simplified because it's an entire university degree all to itself]
You can't really add mass or even practical damping or air-gapping to windows unless you add more panes - double or triple glazing. Both of these add not only mass but also rather spectacular air-gapping. Leaving a gap between two surfaces means that the transmission of sound between them is lessened as some of the air 'absorbs' the sound.
Double-glazing improves this by actually removing a lot of the air between the panes, thereby reducing the remaining air's ability to transmit at all.
DIY 'fake' double glazing that you stick up inside existing single pane will help a bit with heat retention in winter, but not to any significant degree for noise transmission.

Adding a bit of weather-seal strip round a single-glazed window will reduce marginally the sound that manages to squeeze through the gap. Practically it will only affect the high-end, the 'treble'. I would imagine your issue is more 'bassy' than that.

If you're next to a busy road, double-glazing will reduce the transmission to more bearable levels, but even triple-glazing will not silence it. For that you need mass. The walls themselves will vibrate in resonance to traffic noise. To reduce that noticeably would require literally another wall, air-gapped & mechanically separated from the first.

Egg-boxes, foam or 'sound insulation' you get from a DIY store will not impact this to any degree comparable to the cost. As the other answer mentions, blocking foam up against the panes will damp their resonance, but not to any great degree.